# Who is (was?) this DC Comics villain?

Tags: dc, comics, character-identification

I first read a DC comics story with this villain back in the 80's. Some things I remember about the character:

- He is portrayed as the bringer of the end of the world
- His name had some connection to Armageddon or apocalypse or something like that
- He was said to have his base "at the end of time"
- In the story I read, he was fighting some time-traveling heroes (the time machine they traveled in looked like a sphere)

Comment: You mentioned [Doomsday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_(comics)) in a comment, the name would fit, and the wiki article does mention that Superman stranded him at the "End of Time" and that an underling of Braniac later retrieved him from there, see the section titled "The Doomsday Wars" as well as the sentence immediately before it. But the character who actually has a *base* at the end of time, as opposed to just getting stranded there, is [The Time Trapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Trapper).

Comment: @Hypnosifl, The Time Trapper actually looks like the character! Well, after I saw him I am quite sure that he is the villain in that story.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I suggested this one in a comment, but since you confirmed it as plausible I'll make it an answer: [The Time Trapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Trapper), who according to the wiki article does have a lair at "the end of time", and among various possible backstories for him, one is that he is "the living embodiment of Entropy in the Universe" (the footnote says that this idea originates from [*Legion of Superheroes* (vol. 4) #4 (1990)](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Legion_of_Super-Heroes_Vol_4_4), and the [Legion of Super-Heroes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_of_Super-Heroes) were a group of time-traveling heroes from the 30th and 31st century, so you may have seen some story where they battled the Time Trapper--a bunch of pages from one such story can be seen [here](http://heshouldreallyknowbetter.blogspot.com/2012/10/these-are-few-of-my-favorite-things.html)). [Here](http://www.dcuguide.com/chronology.php?name=timetrapper) is a list of stories in which the Time Trapper has appeared.

Comment: My money is on this, rather than my own suggestion. I was just perusing his Wiki article myself, and he seems to fit even better than Darkseid.

Answer (score 11):

Do you mean [Darkseid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darkseid)? He is very similar to the more famous *Marvel* super-villain Thanos - who is a rip-off of Darkseid, by his creator's own admission - and ticks several of your boxes. He is from the planet [Apokolips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apokolips), and his primary goal is to eliminate free will from the universe, essentially making every living thing an extension of his own consciousness. Think Loki's staff in *The Avengers* film, but way more powerful.

The storyline you are thinking of is probably "[The Great Darkness Saga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Darkness_Saga)," which is set one thousand years in the future. It features Darkseid battling the [Legion of Super-Heroes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_of_Super-Heroes), who are time-travellers.

Comment: Thanks James Sheridan, I took a look at Darkseid and to be frank I cannot recall how the villain looked like. On another hand the article you linked to mentioned another character named Doomsday. Do you know if Doomsday ever battled any time-traveling group of heroes?

Comment: @x457812: No, to my knowledge Doomsday has never fought the Legion of Super-Heroes, nor any other time-travelling group of heroes. He certainly never fought them in a concerted story-arc; possibly as a one-off, or in one of the universe-wide story-arcs involving Doomsday and/ or Darkseid. I only know Doomsday's actions in the 'regular' *DC* universe, however, which means that if he did something in an alternate universe title, I wouldn't be aware of it.

Comment: I would have considered Darkseid more famous, but that's probably changed since Thanos has a role in the MCU.